# using airflow with Dbt debug: User does not have permissions for this command: "git"

Tags: git, airflow, dbt

I am making project using airflow with dbt. When I use AirflowBashOperator with bash command `dbt debug` I get error for git saying that I don't have permission for "git". How can I solve this error?

The debug return is:

```
Configuration:
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -   profiles.yml file [[32mOK found and valid[0m]
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -   dbt_project.yml file [[32mOK found and valid[0m]
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - Required dependencies:
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -  - git [[31mERROR[0m]
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - Connection:
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -   host: ****
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -   port: ****
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -   user: ***
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -   database: ***
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -   schema: ****
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -   search_path: ***
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -   keepalives_idle: ***
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -   sslmode: ****
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -   Connection test: [[32mOK connection ok[0m]
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - [31m1 check failed:[0m
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - Error from git --help: User does not have permissions for this command: "git"
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {subprocess.py:96} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
[2022-08-09, 10:55:52 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1889} ERROR - Task failed with exception
```

Comment: `[[31m` are [standard terminal color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors). The real error is **User does not have permissions for this command: "git"**

Comment: Note that I don't use Airflow and cannot answer specific questions about it, but it's quite clear that this is a matter of airflow's command-permissions security model. See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.6/security.html?highlight=ldap for example.